# django get_absolute_url redirecting issue

Tags: django

I have an object from which I want to have two get_absolute_urls, since I have two categories(rent,sale). However, if I set get_absolute_url 'rent' last, the items from sale are redirecting to 'rents' url ex: rents/1.

How can I make this to work?

model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    bedrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, blank = True, null = True)
    garage = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    sqft = models.IntegerField()
    categories= (('sale', 'sale'),('rent','rent'))
    category= models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices= categories,  null = True)
    lot_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True, null = True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True, null = True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True, null = True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True, null = True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sale', args=[str(self.id)])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rent', args=[str(self.id)])
```

urls

```
path('rents/',rents, name = 'rents'),
path('rents/<int:pk>',RentView.as_view(), name = 'rent'),

path('sales/',sales, name = 'sales'),
path('sales/<int:pk>',SaleView.as_view(), name = 'sale'),
```

html

```
   <a href="{{ item_vip.get_absolute_url }}"><button class='btn-view fntmk'>View</button></a>
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure if python works the same but you override the previous function definition with the last one which in this case is your "rent" one. can you not pass in the "rent/sale" as an argument to it? and call it later like ```my_model.get_absolute_url("sale")``` ?

Comment: I have to check how to override method in python, since in C# you can do it with virtual on the met. However, I fix the problem. "sales/{{ item.pk}}" "rents/{{ item.pk }}"

Comment: ok overriding is the wrong word because you re-define it... even in c# you have to have unique method signatures (overloading)  ... overriding a method happens when you use inheritance ... in python you don't explicitly say ```override``` you just redefine the parents method in your child :-D  .. anyway, you fixed it ... maybe then post your own answer and the changes you applied to the code to fix it.

Comment: Instead of using `get_absolute_url()`, why not define `get_sale_url(self):...` and `get_rent_url(self):...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two categories `rent` and `sale`, you can use `if` statement inside `get_absolute_url`.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.category == 'sale':
        return reverse('sale', args=[str(self.id)])
    else:
        return reverse('rent', args=[str(self.id)])
```

But you have set `null=True` in `category= models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices= categories,  null = True)`

So you need to handle the case when category is `null`.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.category == 'sale':
        return reverse('sale', args=[str(self.id)])
    elif self.category == 'rent':
        return reverse('rent', args=[str(self.id)])
    else:
        return '/' # Handler null case
```